# Are `where * contains ` and `search` the same operator in KQL?

Tags: azure, search, contains, kql, azure-log-analytics

Are `where * contains`  and `search` the same operator in KQL?

E.g. are the following queries identical?

```
union *
| where * contains "foo"
```

and

```
union *
| search "foo"
```

I tried to find anything about the `search` keyword, but found nothing, since all the results are polluted with something unrelated to the keyword. It seems people usually use the word `search` along with anything KQL related.

While I know that the `where * contains "foo"` will get all results which have the case incensitive `"foo"` in any column's value.

I need to know the answer to this question, since the `search` is shorter than the `where * contains` and I would like to use the `search` instead. But I am not sure if I will get any different behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my observations:

Yes, `where * contains "x"` is similar to `serach "x"` as it has similar functionality but outputs are little different:

Using  **`where * contains`** :

[image]

Using **`Search`**:

[image]

Here, you could clearly see 1 more column named $table is added to the table, I would say that both have `similar functionality` but gives different results.

One use with search is that you do not need to use pipe | operator if you are searching in table like below:

```
search in (Table name) "Error"
```

[image]

For further you can refer on [search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/searchoperator#search-predicate-syntax-examples).

**`Note:`**

Where is used to find in a single table , where as Search will find in all tables in a particular cluster